# Automatic evaluation of written English - e.g. item descriptions

Tags: syntax, nlp, written-language

I'm looking for S/W that evaluates the quality of short English texts, e.g. in terms of grammar, syntax, maybe style or ethnicity. My interest is, for example, in descriptions of items offered for sale on Web sites or via email, not essays.

Are there any packages I can try, preferably open source?